# Dynamically Load Collapsible Set in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, html

I am trying to dynamically load a nested collapsible-set using ajax call in JQuery Mobile. For some reason, the collapsible div end up showing on the same level; not hierarchical or nested.

Here is the code:

```
    $('#pp-home').live("pageinit", function(){
        //Get Colleges
        $.ajax({url: "parent.php?action=xyz", 
            success:function(data){
                $(data).find('college').each(function(){
                    $('#colleges_div').append(
                        "<div id='col_"+$(this).attr('id')+"' data-role='collapsible' data-theme='c'>"+
                            "<h3>"+$(this).text()+"</h3><p>ssss</p>"+
                        "</div>"
                    );
                    //Get data
                    $.ajax({url:"children.php?action=xyz", 
                        success:function(data){
                            $(data).find('dept').each(function(){
                                $("#col_"+$(this).attr('cid')).append(
                                    "<div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='a' data-mini='true'>"+
                                        "<h3>"+$(this).text()+"</h3><p>ssss</p>"+
                                    "<div>"
                                );
                            $("#col_"+$(this).attr('cid')).trigger('create');
                            }); 
                        }
                    });
                });
                $('#colleges_div').trigger('create');
            }
        });     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods for Collapsible Content are:

```
$( ".selector" ).trigger( "collapse" ); 
$( ".selector" ).trigger( "expand" );
```

See more: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible.html

For a Collapsible-set, you have:

```
$( ".selector" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
```

See More: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html

I am in a similar boat, currently, yet trying to nest a collapsiuble list within a collapsible set: http://jsfiddle.net/MqDFt/3/

Looking at what could be resulting as HTML, I think you are missing a parent that is defined as the collapsible-set. The format should be:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="parent1">
  <div data-role="collapsible" id="child1">
    <h3>Header Title 1</h3>
    <p>ssss</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible" id="child2">
    <h3>Header Title 2</h3>
    <p>ssss</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then when you call $("#parent1").collapsibleset("refresh"), it should display properly.